# , throwing an error in $.ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I think I have entirely to many variables, but I cant exactly not have them as they are all vital to the controller that recieves the POST data.

Its breaking around tv: tv, which PHP Eclipse turns the , red, but doesnt tell me what the problem is. Chromes console says its unexpected identifier. Whats going on here?

Ive looked everywhere in these questions and I cant find anything like this.

How can I fix it and still use all these form fields?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $('.pa-details-submit ul li a').attr('href'),
    data: {
        make_active_check: make_active_check,
        details_title: details_title,
        details_country: details_country,
        details_desc: details_desc,
        details_price: details_price,
        details_zipcode: details_zipcode,
        details_state: details_state,
        details_city: details_city,
        details_add: details_add,
        details_hidden: details_hidden,
        featured: featured,
        bedrooms: bedrooms,
        baths: baths,
        beds: beds,
        floor: floor,
        sleeps: sleeps,
        couches: couches,
        door: door,
        laundry: laundry,
        dishwasher: dishwasher,
        furnished: furnished,
        elevator: elevator,
        mon: mon,
        tue: tue,
        wed: wed,
        thu: thu,
        fri: fri,
        sat: sat,
        sun: sun,
        pets_allowed: pets_allowed,
        cabletv: cabletv,
        tv: tv,
        wireless_net,
        net: net,
        handicap: handicap,
        dvd: dvd,
        pay_parking: pay_parking,
        free_parking: free_parking,
        ac: ac,
        heat: heat,
        gym: gym,
        family_friendly: family_friendly,
        smoking: smoking,
        pool: pool,
        washer: washer,
        dryer: dryer
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('.messages').html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: NOTE if i change the , to a period (.) it makes the error go away but sends empty post data.

Comment: So you defined all those variables in javascript? make_active_check, details_title,...

Comment: I would suspect a character problem, like some goofy unicode got inserted or something. I'd delete it starting with the offending line and retype it.

Comment: yes I can paste the WHOLE code if you want.. Pretty much im pulling the class with $('.class').val() when the SAVE button is pressed, and sending the vars through AJAX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
wireless_net,
```

is just a property name, with no value assigned.

Try:

```
// or whatever variable should set the 'wireless_net' property
wireless_net: wireless_net,
```

So your error was right after `tv: tv,`

Comment: Ofcourse. How could i be so foolish LOL :P Thanks a million and one.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps its while  wireless_net does not have value.

Answer (score 1):

wireless_net has no param name specified. Line should be something like:

wireless_net: wireless_net,